# VB Database not updating after saving and closing application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to have my program update the database when you type in new information and save it, everything else is working in my application but it is not saving my changes when I reload the application. What seems to be the error?

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private DBPath As String

```
Private conn As OleDbConnection
Private adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Private dtMain As DataTable
Private dataSet As DataSet
Private cmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DBPath = Application.StartupPath + "\MEGACITIES.mdb"
    conn = New OleDbConnection(Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=") & DBPath)
    conn.Open()
    If Not File.Exists(DBPath) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please copy the mdb to the path: " + Application.StartupPath)

    Else
        ' connect to DB        
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Cities]", conn)
        Dim builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        dataSet = New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Cities")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Cities")
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnPopulationByOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPopulationByOrder.Click

    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Cities] order by pop2015", conn)
    Dim builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    'dtMain = New DataTable()
    'adapter.Fill(dtMain)
    'DataGridView1.DataSource = dtMain
    dataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Cities")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Cities")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Cities.city,Cities.country,Cities.pop1995,Countries.currency FROM [Cities] inner join Countries on Cities.country = Countries.country", conn)
    Dim builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    dataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Cities")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Cities")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim() = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the country name in text box.")
    Else

        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT city from [Cities] where country = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conn)
        Dim builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        dataSet = New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Cities")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Cities")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    cmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    adapter.Update(dataSet, "Cities")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("Cities")
    MessageBox.Show("1 changed Records were stored", "Project4Spring2016")

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: None of the code you've posted makes any effort to modify the data. If you're not changing anything, why would you expect things to change? There's nothing to save, and no modifications to reflect when the app restarts. Even though you're calling `adapter.Update(dataSet, "Cities")`, you're doing nothing that would change the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an update sql statement on the records your try to save. It appears right now all you have are select statements